# List of modified files in XCode 4

Tags: xcode4

How do I get to see all the local modified files with respect to the sub-version copy as a list?

XCode 3 had a shortcut and a view to show these from where we could commit the code too: cmd+shift+v

I see no alternative to it in XCode 4. Anyone knows how?

Thanks,
Raj

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In the Project Navigator (the normal source tree view), take a look at the buttons along the bottom edge (to the left of the search filter field). The middle button turns on a filter that shows only files with source control status (uncommitted changes).

Comment: But personally, which interface do you feel better? xCode 3x or xCode 4?

Comment: I like where 4 is going, I just think it needs to mature a bit more before I'm comfortable saying "I like it better".

Answer (score 0):

Bottom right corner of Filter (selected state) of Project Navigator, their is button for "Show only files with source-control status", by pressing this button it will show only modified files in Project Navigator.

[image]